# What is koshinashi?

Tags: meaning, definitions

I can't find コシなし defined in any dictionary. It looks like it might have something to do with udon noodles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From goo dictionary:

腰がある

餅・うどん・そばなどの歯ざわりがしっかりしている。

English example:

この餅は腰がある
This rice cake is chewy.

For noodles, 'chewy' is probably not the best choice. I've seen it equated to *al dente* in English and that is probably a better translation.

コシなし would be the opposite, what we might call soggy noodles in English.

Comment: +1 for something so specific (and spot-on) as "al dente"